# Python: time data '19. Mai 2020' does not match format '%d. %b %Y'

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

I've got no idea, why the heck this won't work..

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = "19. Mai 2020"
date1 = datetime.strptime(d, "%d. %B %Y")
```

As a result, I get the following error code:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-78591e667c99> in <module>()
----> 1 date1 = datetime.strptime(s, "%d. %B %Y")

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    360     if not found:
    361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 362                          (data_string, format))
    363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '19. Mai 2020' does not match format '%d. %B %Y'
```

After 48h of studying several tutorials, I still don't have a clue...

Hopefully, one of you does see my .. mistake?

Regards, 
P!

Comment: Mai is normally spelled May.  Typo? Or different locale?

Comment: Exactly. This is the german expression for "May". ... ahh... is it possible, that I have to tell python, that this is german?

Comment: This did the trick... The change from "Mai" to "May" lead to a correct process. But how do I tell python, that this is the german dateformat?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the appropriate locale is set, strptime will respect that:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")
'de_DE'
>>> datetime.strptime("19. Mai 2020", "%d. %B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 19, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought, that the language would be set automatically by respecting the system language and datetime. I work with a german interface and pycharm. May I ask, where I have to add this line of code? I need this for a scrapy project. Thank you! (y)

Comment: You can do that in environment before entering Python, e.g. `LC_ALL=de_DE python3 -c "import locale; print(locale.getlocale())"`

Comment: Thank you, wim! I'll try that later on, when I am back home! :-)

Comment: It seems, that I cannot change the language to "de_DE". May I ask, where to set the German language? (venv) rhino@rhino-pc newspage % locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")
zsh: number expected
(venv) rhino@rhino-pc newspage  % locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE.UTF-8")
zsh: number expected

Comment: Try `export LC_ALL=de_DE` before entering Python.